# get column names from excel using exceljs / xlsx in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx, exceljs

I am using `exceljs` to fetch data from excel.  I have written the below code. I am able to get the values inside the rows. But, I am not understanding how to get the column names.

```
let workbook = new ExcelJs.Workbook();
  workbook.xlsx.load(edata).then(async function(wb){
    wb.eachSheet((sheet, id) => {
      sheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: false }, function(row, rowIndex) {
      console.log(row.values)
      })
    })
})
```

Please help me in fetching the column names. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json` :

```
const [columns] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[YOUR_SHEET_NAME], { header: 1 });
```